# when i click on the image it should display in textarea .,like smiley

Tags: php, jquery

i have problem in displaying an image in textarea 
please help me to solve it
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As anothershrubery already mentioned, textarea can only hold plain text.

You can instead use a `div` element with the [`contenteditable`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#contenteditable) attribute set to `true`.

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    You can edit this text and also add images! <img src="smiley.jpg" alt=":)" />
</div>
```

There are also many different JavaScript [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editors which uses the above method or an `iframe` in [`designmode`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#designMode).

Here's a couple of them:

- [Aloha Editor](http://www.aloha-editor.org/)
- [MarkItUp](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/)
- [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)
- [Lightweight RTE](http://batiste.dosimple.ch/blog/posts/2007-09-11-1/rich-text-editor-jquery.html)
- [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

Answer (score 4):

Textareas can only hold plain text. Use [contenteditable](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#contenteditable) or a fully functional editor, like [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) to save you the troubles.

Comment: Please do not refer to w3schools.com. Use proper sources that aren't run by economic interests... See [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: @Marcus And added again http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_global_contenteditable.asp w3schools is accurate on this page, and a hell of a lot more readable for a beginner than the W3 spec. There is no reason to carpet-bomb w3schools links - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource

Comment: @Blowski, doesn't matter if that specific page is accurate or not. They already proven themselves not to be a reliable source and should especially not be given to beginners since they will most certainly use that site to look up other things that might be incorrect. I do not agree with Bill on meta :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot display images in a textarea. Textarea's just accept plain text.

Answer (score 1):

Textarea support text only, if you want to display image/ link or any thing else, use WYSIWYG HTML Editor

You can try this, a really good one ;)

http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="image_txtarea" style="width:auto"> 
<img src="image/Example.jpg" id="image" style="position:absolute"/>
<textarea id="some" style="position:absolute;display:none"></textarea>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#image').click(function(){
    var img = $('#image');
    $(this).hide().next('textarea').show().css({'background':'url('+ img.attr('src') +') no-repeat center center','width':img.width(),'height':img.height()});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, image can be placed in textarea.

I placed an animated gif in textarea (worked in `ie-6` and `ff-13.0.1`) with this technique:

1. Convert any image into a `base64` string. (free online converters available, there is a limit to the base 64 file size - around 30k image size); a simple `url()` background statement did not show image for me.
2. The online converters usually output both an `<img>` tag and a CSS background property with the correct values from the uploaded image. Just copy and paste the CSS output into your own file. use url data statement - `url(data:image/ext.....)`
3. use the `base64` css as a background in the style statement.
4. to change images, you'll have to change `div id=""` or `class` where you have base 64 defined as `background-image` in the `class` or `id`.
5. time consuming to do conversions so make sure that you really want an image in a textarea before you start.